# Linear method to circle fitting using least squares method

Tags: python, math

I'm currently using an algebraic method for circle fitting using LSF (ie Matrix Ax = B) with reference to this paper:

[image: Solving by Matrix]

It's the method I primarily use since I understand the process behind it compared to other methods published by different research papers. The issue is that the plotting gets wonky after the coordinates go upward to ~500 (and more), and the center of the circle can go upwards to x^(10^8).

I would first like to excuse the bad code writing since I am trying to make it clear what I'm doing. Below is a snippet. I did not include the plotting code as I feel like it's more of a math/coding issue.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for num in range(N):
    point = input('Input coordinate of point {}: '.format(num+1))

    # splitting the coordinates into x and y respectively
    point_x = float(point.split()[0])
    points_x.append(point_x)

    # getting the x summations
    sum_x += point_x
    sum_x_squared += point_x**2
    sum_x_cubed += point_x**3

    # getting the y summations
    point_y = float(point.split()[1])
    points_y.append(point_y)
    sum_y += point_y
    sum_y_squared += point_y**2
    sum_y_cubed += point_y**3

    # getting the xy summations
    sum_xy += point_x * point_y
    sum_xsq_y += point_x**2 * point_y
    sum_x_ysq += point_x * point_y**2

    points.append((point_x, point_y))

# after differentiation, represent the equations in the form of a matrix
# matrix1 represents the matrix with coefficients A B C
# ie [0 1 2][A B C] = [9 4 2] where [0 1 2] is matrix1
matrix1 = np.array([[sum_x_squared, sum_xy, sum_x],
                   [sum_xy, sum_y_squared, sum_y],
                   [sum_x, sum_y, len(points)]])

# matrix2 represents the constant ie [9 4 2]
matrix2 = np.array([[sum_x*(sum_x_squared + sum_y_squared)],
                   [sum_y*(sum_x_squared + sum_y_squared)],
                   [sum_x_squared + sum_y_squared]])

# solving the matrix
center_x = np.linalg.solve(matrix1, matrix2)[0]/2
center_y = np.linalg.solve(matrix1, matrix2)[1]/2
radius = math.sqrt(np.linalg.solve(matrix1, matrix2)[2] + (center_x)**2 + (center_y)**2)/2

# hence, we obtain the equation of circle
print('Equation of best fit circle: (x-{})^2 + (y-{})^2 = {}^2'.format(center_x, center_y, radius))
```

**Input**

```
Number of points: 8
Input coordinate of point 1: 987.091 1028.443
Input coordinate of point 2: 992.504 1021.98
Input coordinate of point 3: 991.764 1013.589
Input coordinate of point 4: 985.328 1008.178
Input coordinate of point 5: 976.959 1008.871
Input coordinate of point 6: 971.523 1015.297
Input coordinate of point 7: 972.204 1023.683
Input coordinate of point 8: 978.459 1029.105
```

**Output**

```
Equation of best fit circle: (x-[1.13510241e+08])^2 + (y-[1.18346499e+08])^2 = 163981720.40047127^2
```

**Plotted with matplotlib (excluding the black lines)**
[image: Plot]

I wanted the circle to fit within the constraints (represented by the blacklines) but I did not get the output I expected. Could I ask for some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

According to the equation you are giving, the column vector you expect is given by the solution of inverse(A)*B = x, I think that's why it doesn't work. The right way to do it is

```
# solving the matrix
matrix1_inv = np.linalg.inv(matrix1)
solution = np.linalg.solve(matrix1_inv, matrix2)
center_x = solution[0]/2
center_y = solution[1]/2
radius = math.sqrt(solution[2]/2 + (center_x)**2 + (center_y)**2)/2
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think it worked. I read on the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve) and the `np.linalg.solve` solves the parameters in the form A*x = B. With your solution it looks more like inverse(A)*x = B.

Comment: Hi, I got confused by the matrix math, you are right, then I don't see where it could be wrong, maybe you should check that the elements of the matrix2 are being calculated correctly

Comment: Ah I had to review it again last night and I managed to get the answer, think it was a math concept issue. Thanks for the help!